# When is thread safety an issue?

Tags: c#, multithreading, redirect

Thread safety is not so much important when you instance classes and use their methods to start the thread correcT?

Comment: Not sure if this would help, but check out an answer I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187568/delays-when-reading-process-output-asynchronously/5187715#5187715

Answer (score 0):

If multiple threads are accessing the same object instance, then you need to add locking to ensure thread safety:

```
// make sure that this is defined *outside* the method
// so that all threads lock on the same instance
private readonly object _lock = new object();

...

// add a lock inside your event handler
proc.OutputDataReceived += (object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
{
    if (e.Data != null)
    {
        lock (_lock)
           info.additional += e.Data;
    }
};
```

As a side note, if you are using .NET 4, you might want to check the [`ConcurrentQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) class. It's a thread safe implementation of a FIFO buffer, which can be useful if multiple threads need to enqueue their items simultaneously:

```
private ConcurrentQueue<SomeInfo> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<SomeInfo>();

...

proc.OutputDataReceived += (object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
{
    if (e.Data != null)
    {
        // no need to lock
        _queue.Enqueue(e.Data);
    }
};
```

To dequeue items in a separate thread, you would use:

```
SomeData data = null;
while (_queue.TryDequeue(out data))
{
    // do something with data
}
```

Comment: Multiple threads are not accessing the same object. Creating an instance of a class that starts the processes for each thread.

Comment: The queue is not the problem. It's the output redirection I believe.

Comment: @Joey: add this to the event handler: `Console.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);`. I believe that you should get different thread IDs written to console.

Comment: I ran the executable four times and here was the status throughout: Got 15 15 7 15 (First program output caputured successful, Then second program output not captured) then 15 15 15 15 (first program output captured succesful, then second program output not captured). Not sure what this means?