# Application Freezes on "StandardOutput.ReadLine()".

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, c#-4.0, process

Application hangs when attempting to call "StandardOutput.ReadLine()".

The code:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("c:\\windows\\system32\\myTesting.exe");
            String s = " ";

            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("list volume\n");
            String f = "";

            while (!p.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
                {
                    s = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                }
```

"Deadlock exception"-error occurs sometimes, but not always.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767496/standardoutput-endofstream-hangs

Answer (score 0):

perhabs the wihle is the problem. Just try this:

```
// Create the child process.
 Process p = new Process();

 // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

 //setting the application path
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "Write500Lines.exe";
 p.Start();

 // Do not wait for the child process to exit before
 // reading to the end of its redirected stream.
 // Read the output stream first and then wait.
 string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Could you include some narrative explaining your code, so the OP knows what you did and why it is an answer to their question?