# Output of running command prompt

Tags: c#

In this following code whenever I send any command like dir or anything this function get stuck in while loop.
I want the output of the command prompt each time I send it command to execute without closing the process after the execution of command.

```
public void shell(String cmd)
{
        ProcessStartInfo PSI = new ProcessStartInfo();
        PSI.FileName = "c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";
        PSI.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        PSI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        PSI.RedirectStandardError = true;
        PSI.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process p = Process.Start(PSI);
        StreamWriter CSW = p.StandardInput;
        StreamReader CSR = p.StandardOutput;
        CSW.WriteLine(cmd);
        CSW.Flush();
        while(!(CSR.EndOfStream))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(CSR.ReadLine());
        }

        CSR.Close();

}
```

Following is the complete code :-

```
 namespace ConsoleApplication8
 {

     class Program
     {
         public static void shell(String cmd)
         {

             ProcessStartInfo PSI = new ProcessStartInfo();
             PSI.FileName = "c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";
             PSI.RedirectStandardInput = true;
             PSI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
             PSI.RedirectStandardError = true;
             PSI.UseShellExecute = false;
             Process p = Process.Start(PSI);
             StreamWriter CSW = p.StandardInput;
             StreamReader CSR = p.StandardOutput;
             CSW.WriteLine(cmd);
             CSW.Flush();
             while (!(CSR.EndOfStream))
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(CSR.ReadLine());
             }

             CSR.Close();

         }
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             string cmd="";
             while (cmd != "exit")
             {
            cmd=Console.ReadLine();
            shell(cmd);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Purpose --> I want to create a program that gives user access to execute commands of command prompt. Above program create cmd.exe process each time it sends some command. But that is not a great problem. I can easily fix that.. The main problem is that each time I send a command the program get stuck at while (!(CSR.EndOfStream))

Comment: why are u using streams? what is purpose? post entire code and look at example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx

Comment: There is a similar question dealing with this. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767496/standardoutput-endofstream-hangs

Comment: Consider writing your result to a file, then read the file. The trick is to know when the output of the command is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this code

```
         ProcessStartInfo PSI = new ProcessStartInfo();
         PSI.FileName = "c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";
         //PSI.RedirectStandardInput = true;
         PSI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
         PSI.RedirectStandardError = true;
         PSI.UseShellExecute = false;
         Process p = Process.Start(PSI);
         StreamWriter CSW = p.StandardInput;

         string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); 

         Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: I tried this code but it get stuck at 
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

Comment: You can delete PSI.RedirectStandardInput = true; i think that you don't need

Comment: RedirectStandardInput has to be true since he is writing to the StandardInput

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate your issue with cmd.exe hanging when writing directly to the input stream. When you run the program like this, .NET can't tell when the output stream has finished so it hangs indefinitely when you call ReadToEnd() (or if you use a while until end of stream). Your best bet is to do something like this where you start cmd.exe with a command supplied as an argument. Then it will know to close the output stream when it has finished executing the command, returning control back to the caller.

Here is an example.

```
static void Main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("> ");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        string output = RunCommand(input);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}

static string RunCommand(string command)
{
    Process p = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()  {
        FileName = "cmd",
        Arguments = "/c \"" + command + "\"",
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    });

    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();
    return output + error;
}
```

Here is an example of the output this will produce,

```
> echo hello, world
hello, world

> ping google.com

Pinging google.com [74.125.225.199] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 74.125.225.199: bytes=32 time=63ms TTL=49
Reply from 74.125.225.199: bytes=32 time=61ms TTL=49
Reply from 74.125.225.199: bytes=32 time=61ms TTL=49
Reply from 74.125.225.199: bytes=32 time=61ms TTL=49

Ping statistics for 74.125.225.199:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 61ms, Maximum = 63ms, Average = 61ms

>
```

Comment: this code get stuck at 
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

and I don't want to exit from the command prompt..

Comment: I know this idea... each timeyou send it command.. it executes it and wait for process to end.. but what if I do cd .. and then again cd.. and then I want to see dir... If I will do that in the program it will not work.. So I don't want process to exit...